# Способ протестировать работу Facebook invites

Tags: android, facebooksdk

Можно ли протестировать работу инвайтов в приложении которое находится еще на стадии разработки и в PlayMarket его еще нету. Приложение зарегистрировано в Facebook, для него создан  Applink в Facebook и Deep link в самом приложении , два тестовых юзера Facebook. Я логинюсь под тестовыми юзерами и пытаюсь отправить инвайты друг другу, но инвайты не приходят. 
Вопрос, правильный способ проверки мною выбран, и если нет, то как это правильно делатся?